# HttpStatus 406 "not acceptable" when returning Flux<String> on Spring 4.3.7 MVC Controller to a EventSource in html page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, eventsource

Im trying to make a timer of how much time a page is open via spring webflux, i had made this example work on springboot but with spring mvc is not working, so i know the code does work. may i have to set up something im not aware of?

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/timer", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Flux<String> startTimer(){
        Instant startTime = Instant.now();
        return Flux.fromStream(
                Stream.generate(() -> calculateTimeMethod(startTime, Instant.now()))
        ).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    }
}
```

JSP home.jsp :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Home </title>
</head>
<body>
    <label> tiempo trascurrido </label>
    <label id="timer"></label>

    <script>
        var eventSource = new EventSource("url/timer");
        eventSource.onmessage = function ( event ) {
            document.getElementById("timer").innerText = event.data;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

home page load but timer doesnt start, console output shows: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (No Aceptable)

Comment: what is the "url/timer" what is "url/" in your code? please double check the console in your web browser that the call is done to the correct url.

Comment: "url/" is just the server url base, example: localhost:8080/timer, and yes the call is done, the controller does execute its code without any problems but the response on the browser says 406 not aceptable

Comment: can you please check check the console in your web browser for your rest call and either post a screenshot of it so that we can see exactly how the rest call looks. Because 406 is usually a header problem from the calling client. Are you sending an Accept header

Comment: Spring Framework 5.0.8 and 5.1.0.RC1, so Spring Boot 2.0.4 and 2.1.0.M1. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13635